# get image from Firebase storage. GlideApp unresolved reference

Tags: kotlin, android-glide

I have tried literally every solution on the web to try and resolve `GlideApp` with no success.  Is there another method I can use to retrieve an image from Firebase Storage and put into an `ImageView` instead of glide?  I worry that if it's this hard to find a solution to using Glide initially, what's gonna happen down the line?  Google recommends it, but I just cannot get it to work.  Here's what I'm implementing:

```
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1"
Implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.3.1"
kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1"1
```

and here's my fragment code:

```
val storageRef = data.getReference()
val pathReference = storageRef.child(user?.uid.toString() + "/images/coverphoto")
GlideApp.with(context)
        .load(pathReference)
        .into();
```

It really shouldn't be this difficult to initially use Glide.

I should mention that this is a kotlin project and that I am trying to access the image in a fragment.

Just in case you need it:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed"
    }
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:0.9'
    implementation 'com.beust:klaxon:3.0.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.3.1"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

****2nd Update****

Here's my ful gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ntx_deisgns.cyberchatter.cyberchatter"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        customDebugType {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed"
    }
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
dependencies {
//    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-common:0.9'
    implementation 'com.beust:klaxon:3.0.1'
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.7.1'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.6.1"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.7.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Comment: Btw, I am Android studio 3.1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this class *anywhere* in your `app` module and it'll work:

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule

@GlideModule
class RequiredAppGlideModule : AppGlideModule()
```

And don't forget the glide compiler:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.7.1'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.6.1"
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.7.1'
```

And make sure you also do

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Comment: I added the Glide Module into my app as well calling the file CcAppGlideModule.kt and pasted your code directly into it.  Then I imported `import com.ntx_deisgns.cyberchatter.cyberchatter.app.RequiredAppGlideModule` into my fragment activity.  I also updated the implementations and plugins with your code above, and I still get the unresolved reference error.  I also did a clean project just in case.  Still not working.

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with how your dependency ends with `"1`. Technically you have to add the `@GlideModule`, add the compiler with `kapt` scope, and apply `kotlin-kapt` and it should work. It works for us. O_O

Comment: I update my original question with the full build.gradle file.  I removed the `"1` from the end of that line when I added your dependencies.  I also tried removing other dependencies to see if they were interfering with Glide.  And I did an invalidate caches and restart.  None of that seems to work.

Comment: I guess I misstyped or mis copied something.  I no longer have the unresolved reference error.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by :

- Click menu Build
- Click Make Module

And GlideApp Class will automatically generated